# How to attach XML file in message body of HTTP post request?

Tags: java, android

How to attach XML file in message body of HTTP post request?

can any one give example for that kind

Comment: plz refer it....http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingCalendars

Comment: i am making google calendar ...and i use Oauth for authorization and i m getting list of event ...and i want to add event in google calendar ...so i have to send HTTP post...and URL is https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full

Comment: sorry .. but i don't know how to send XML file in message body of HTTP post ..so i not start for HTTP post..thnx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4192/discussion-between-sanket-kachhela-and-pm-paresh-mayani)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a sample code snippet for making HTTP POST request on the desired URL:

```
try { 

String myXML = "<? xml version=1.0> <Request> <Elemtnt> <data id=\"1\">E1203</data> <data id=\"2\">E1204</data> </Element> </Request>";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full"); 

List<NameValuePair> dataToPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 

dataToPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourxml", myXML)); 

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToPost)); 

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext); 

} catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: I saw the code.I have one problem in this line dataToPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourxml", post_your_xml)); What i have write in argument?

Comment: @Gensheriff yes exactly, Create XML string and pass it here.

Comment: Something like that  StringBuilder sb=sb.append("<ArrayOfString>");
sb.append("<string>").sb.append("the_command").sb.append("</string>");
sb.append("</ArrayOfString>");    m  i right or not?

Comment: IF I HAVE ATTRIBUTE in XML tag.Than What i have to write in String?

Comment: @Gensheriff just create a single string of the whole XML. if you have Attribute in XML then escape the string with "\"

Comment: Is there any way to add xml header in message request?